# mysqli_select_db wrong database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to move a web page from one sever to another which I'm not the author (some kind of custom cms). 
My problem with it is that I prints only the message `Wrong database`. I did check the login data with login through phpmyadmin and they work.

On the old server there was a version of php 5.4 and on the new one I have the  7.0 version

```
<?php

$DB->host = 'localhost';
$DB->name = 'db-name';
$DB->pass = 'pass';
$DB->login = 'db-user';
$DB->prefix = '';

$System->files = '';
$System->root = '';
$System->lang['pl'] = 'Polski';
$System->lang['de'] = 'Deutsch';
$System->lang['en'] = 'English';
//$System->lang['ru'] = 'русский';

$System->component->articles = true;
$System->component->references = true;
$System->component->contakt = true;

$link = mysqli_connect($DB->host,$DB->login,$DB->pass) or die ("Can't connect: " . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($DB->name, $link) or die ("Wrong database: " . mysqli_error());
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

unset($link,$DB->name,$DB->login,$DB->pass);
?>
```

Comment: You have the order of arguments to `mysqli_select_db` backwards.

Comment: You can also pass the DB name as an argument to `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: You're also missing the first argument to `mysqli_query()`. This code looks like you took just did a global replace of `mysql_` to `mysqli_`. But the functions in the two extensions take arguments in different order.

Comment: In `mysql_XXX` the `$link` argument is last and is optional. In `mysqli_XXX` the `$link` argument is required and always first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using procedural style `mysqli_select_db` the first parameter is the link identifier then comes the database name

```
mysqli_select_db( $link, $DB->name );
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).

Worth mentioning you have also other issues in your code: see [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s comments.

I suggest you check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for every mysqli function you're using; you should be able to fix things easily.

Comment: He's also missing the `$link` argument to `mysqli_error()` and `mysqli_query()`. He just took mysql code and renamed it to mysqli without fixing up anything else.

Comment: @Barmar yes, you're right. I updated the answer as it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you @Paolo for you help and also for the links.